# Disconnecting while pairing with a remote Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Currently I start the pairing procedure (well it starts automatically to be honest) when i try to do a GATT operation and it fails to successfully complete that operation. Once the pairing procedure is finished and i get bonded with the remote device i continue to do my GATT operations in which everything works just fine.

What i have noticed is that while pairing:

**1)** if i disconnect from the remote device without closing the GATT client then it still pairs successfully and i go into the `BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED` state and my app continues to work just fine.

**2)** if i disconnect and i also close the GATT client then once i go into the `BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED` state then my app crashes

Why does my app crashes when i close the GATT client of the remote device while in the pairing procedure? is that normal or am i doing something wrong?

This is my BroadcastReceiver implementation for getting the bonding state of the remote device

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

            if(state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING){
                DebugWrapper.debugMsg("On Bonding...", TAG);
                mIsBonding = true;
                onBonding();
            } else if(state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                DebugWrapper.debugMsg("On Bonded", TAG);
                mIsBonded = true;

                    mActivity.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

                    /*
                     * finish what we started
                     */
                    if(mBluetoothGatt != null){

                        if(mOperationState == OperationState.READ_CHARACTERISTIC){
                            readCharacteristic(mCurrentCharacteristic);
                        } else if(mOperationState == OperationState.WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC){
                            writeCharacteristic(mCurrentCharacteristic);
                        } else if(mOperationState == OperationState.READ_DESCRIPTOR){
                            readDescriptor(mCurrentDescriptor);
                        } else if(mOperationState == OperationState.WRITE_DESCRIPTOR){
                            writeDescriptor(mCurrentDescriptor);
                        }
                        mOperationState = OperationState.NONE;
                    }

                    onBonded();

            } else if(state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE){
                DebugWrapper.debugMsg("Not Bonded", TAG);
                notBonded();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Update LogCat files (Links to Pastebin.com as the files where too big to be added here)**

**[From this logCat you can see the steps i am following](http://pastebin.com/PVFLRNLd)**

**[App LogCat, complete](http://pastebin.com/igb0qCBK)**

Comment: As with any Android crash, we'd need to see a stack trace from logcat, through to the "Caused by" line(s) and to see the source code surrounding the mentioned lines, with the specific line clearly identified.

Comment: Added my BroadcastReceiver implementation and the LogCat data, there doesn't seem to be a "Caused by" line anywhere in the logcat and this kinda confuses me

Comment: This does not include the crash of your application or any error directly related to your problem, but rather unrelated system quirks likely from the factory.  The messages you need are likely earlier, try it again.

Comment: i have updated my logcat, I have filtered it to only show the error messages and it doesn't really show much. also my app doesn't seem to show a specific error in the logcat. let me know if i copy pasted the wrong logcat

Comment: Don't filter - you still are not posting what is need to understand the issue.  The SIGSEGV might or might not be related, but it would be necessary to see many lines preceding and following it to know.

Comment: i will post a better logcat later

Comment: added complete logcat files links to pastebin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have found a bug in bluedroid, Android's bluetooth stack.

> signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000008

```
backtrace:
#00  pc 0007c86e /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so (GKI_getnext+9)
#01  pc 000bd9e3  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so (gatt_sec_check_complete+10)
#02  pc 000bdde9  /system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so (gatt_enc_cmpl_cback+104)
```

This is a native null pointer exception in [gki/common/gki_buffer.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-4.4.2_r2/gki/common/gki_buffer.c) of Android's "bluedroid" BT stack.

**It happens to be a confusing one**, as at first glance the problematic function appears to be GKI_getnext(), but in reality, it is actually the first instruction of the immediately following function, GKI_queue_is_empty()

```
BOOLEAN GKI_queue_is_empty(BUFFER_Q *p_q)
{
    return ((BOOLEAN) (p_q->count == 0));
}
```

If we look at the actual decompilation,

```
<GKI_queue_is_empty>:
    ldrh    r0, [r0, #8]
    rsbs    r0, r0, #1
    it      cc
    movcc   r0, #0
    bx      lr
```

We see that we are trying to reference the `count` member of the `BUFFER_Q` structure pointed to by r0, however what is happening is that we were called with a NULL buffer, so we add 8 to NULL, and try to load a register from the illegal address `00000008` causing a SIGSEGV.

Going up a level, this is called from gatt_sec_check_complete() - indeed, if we look in [stack/gatt/gatt_auth.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-4.4.2_r1/stack/gatt/gatt_auth.c) we find the first thing it does is check if queue is empty.

```
void gatt_sec_check_complete(BOOLEAN sec_check_ok, tGATT_CLCB   *p_clcb, UINT8 sec_act)
{
    if (GKI_queue_is_empty(&p_clcb->p_tcb->pending_enc_clcb))
        gatt_set_sec_act(p_clcb->p_tcb, GATT_SEC_NONE);
```

But the problem is that the queue isn't empty, rather **it is null**.

So either there is a bug in bluedroid where it doesn't realize that something can be NULL, or else your program is peforming an invalid series of operations which sets the bluedroid stack up for this failure.

Assigning blame however turns out to be simple, because we can look at the security model.  The process which is crashing runs as user `bluetooth` which is a semi-privileged account, not the user id of your application.  Therefore, **as a matter of basic principle, nothing your unprivileged app does should be able to crash it**, and we can categorize this as a bug in the platform bluetooth stack, rather than your application.